# Vue - change input width according to content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html-input, vue-reactivity

So I can do this *(`Pug` & `CoffeeScript`)*:

```
input(placeholder="0", v-model.number="order[index]" v-on:change="adjustInput")
...
adjustInput: ->
    event.target.style.width = event.target.value.length + 'ch'
```

... but it **only works if I change the input in the browser, by hand**. The input does not change its width if the `v-model` changes.

How can I make it so that the input width changes even if the change is due to `Vue` reactivity?

Comment: what's with the downvote?

Comment: Change the event to @input instead of change..

Comment: @chans neither v-on:@input="adjustInput" or @input="adjustInput" seem to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Check this one, but you must check the font-size on input and on fake_div

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
  return {
    order: 1, // your value
    fakeDivWidth: 10, // width from start, so input width = 10px
  };
},
watch: {
  order: {  // if value from input changing
    handler(val) {
      this.inputResize();
    },
  },
},
methods: {
  inputResize() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fakeDivWidth = this.$el.querySelector('.fake_div').clientWidth;
    }, 0);
  },
},
})
```

```css
.fake_div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100500vw;
  top: -100500vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <input placeholder="0" v-model.number="order" v-bind:style="{width: fakeDivWidth + 'px'}" >
<div class="fake_div">{{ order }}</div> // fake_div needed to see this div width
// этот блок фейковый и нужен только для того, что бы наш input становился такого же размера как этот div
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input(placeholder="0", v-model.number="order[index]" v-on:change="adjustInput" :style="{width: reactiveWidth}")

// Your secret Vue code
data() {
   return function() {
       reactiveWidth: 100px; // (some default value)
   }
},
methods: {
  adjustInput() {
     this.reactiveWidth = event.target.value.length + 'ch'
  }
},
computed: {
   reactiveWidth() {
     return this.number + 'ch';
  }
}
```

Since I don't know all parts of the code, you might need to tweak this a bit. With just binding `this.number` to a `order[index]` you are not affecting the width of the input in any way. The computed property listens to changes in number

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround to me is to replace the input field with a `contenteditable span` which will wrap around the text:

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue'

const state = reactive({
    input: 'My width will adapt to the text'
})
</script>


<template>
    <span class="input" @input="e => state.input = e.target.innerText" contenteditable>{{state.input}}</span>
</template>
```

This works like `v-model=state.input`